# Ajax / jQuery Django refresh class of elements

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I was not able to come up with a more fitting title, but my issue is the following:

I generate a list of posts with the option to like and dislike them, depending on if they have already been liked.

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <hr>
        <strong>{{ post.owner }}</strong> </br>
        {{ post.content }} </br>
        <i>{{ post.post_date }}</i> </br>
        <form action="{% url 'like' %}" method="post" class="likeform">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}">
            {% if post.id not in liked_posts_ids %}
                <button type="submit" >Like</button>
            {% else %}
                <button type="submit" >Dislike</button>

            {% endif %}
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

Now, as it is with all websites that use stuff like this, I don't want to refresh the whole website everytime someone clicks the like/dislike button.

My current JS looks like the following:

```
 $(document).on('submit','.likeform',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'like' %}',
            data:{
                post_id: $('#post_id').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
        success:function(){
            $(".likeform").load(" .likeform > *");
        }
    });
```

The POST request works fine, but the `success:function()`part does not. It refreshes all buttons, which is not that nice, but it also puts all buttons in all forms. Currently there are 6 posts in my database which results in 6 like/dislike buttons under every post after `$(".likeform").load(" .likeform > *");`has finished.

How can I only refresh the correct instance of the button, while keeping the buttons generated in the for loop?
Is there a way to leverage the `#post_id`to identify the relevant button?

Comment: You could send the `post_id` back in the `success` callback and use it to select the correct  input element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! As you can probably tell, I am quite new to JS/JQ/AJAX - how is this done?

Comment: Do you intend to show and hide buttons with CSS or remove and replace the buttons completely from the HTML?

Comment: My idea was basically to refresh them via a new request to the backend (in views.py the list of followed post_ids is generated and passed on to the template where the button text is determined based on this list. I am not sure if this is even possible at that point, because it would basically have to re-render the whole template to work, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're doing great. You won't have to re-render everything fortunately. As a response from the server you could send the HTML of the button that should replace the old one. If you are able to modify the response to send the button on a string, like : `"<button type="submit" >Dislike</button>"` then it will be super easy. Or even just the text of `Like` and `Dislike` would do.

Comment: Hm I think I don't get it yet. Take a look at my first code snippet - the template generates buttons for every post in my database and at that point, on a post by post basis during template parsing the button text is being generated, based on the list of liked posts. this list gets generated with every get-request on /timeline/ and passed over to the template. I currently have no idea how I could trigger a new list generation, get only (e.g.) post 4's html with the correctly generated button text. Seems so complicated that there has to be an easy way...:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saying that you have multiple of these forms on you page, lose the `id` attribute on the `input` and change it to a `name` attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}">
```

`id`'s have to be unique and are invalid if they occur more than once. And the `name` attribute is a better identifier of an input element.

In your `$.ajax` function you'll want to get the values from the current form that you have submitted. In that form you want to select all the elements that you need.

Now for the request you need to do something differently. The request should go to a function on the server which updates the value on this post with the id that we sent, if it has been liked or disliked. Nothing further. It should then, as a response, send a text string back which will be the new text value of the submit button.

In your `success` handler you'll need to set the received text string to the button in the submitted form. So when you click `Like`, the server will send a request, the post will be liked on the server, and the server sends back `Dislike`, which is now the text on the button. And when clicking dislike it should do the same thing, disliking the post and returning the `Like` string.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.likeform', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get the currently submitted form and find the inputs
  // inside the form necessary to send the data with.
  var $form = $(this); 
  var $postId = $form.find('input[name="post_id"]');
  var $csrf = $form.find('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]');
  var $button = $form.find('button');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'like' %}',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
      post_id: $postId.val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: $csrf.val()
    },
    success: function(response) {

      // Replace the current text of the button with a new
      // text based on if it was liked or disliked.
      $button.text(response);

    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Okay I can follow you so far, but how would the response have to be for `buttonText` to be set? Can I just `return 'Like'`on my function? `liked_post.save()
            return 'Dislike'` like so? To explain further: /like/ is the endpoint receiving the ajax POST, should the function in my views.py just return a string or how do I go about that?

Comment: The response should either be `"Like"` or `"Dislike"` based on if the post that has the `post_id` that you've sent is either now liked or not. If is liked, send dislike. If is disliked send like. It's like a switch.

Comment: I edited my comment to be more specific - I am questioning if I have to send back a json object or a string or a HttpResponse or anything else, because I don't know exactly how the `success` part gets the response data

Comment: In this case, a string. Because we only need one value: the text of the button. The `success` callback function has a couple of parameters, the first being the body of the response. Thats the way that you can access the response value. I've updated the argument in the callback to be clearer.

Comment: I experimented a little - with a string I got an exception from Django, with a HttpResponse('Like') it works - I cannot thank you enough. People like you make the world a better place.